# Running Netlogo standalone - Corporate Environment

Tags: netlogo

I've used NetLogo to explain the power of agent based modelling to people a number of times and I have found it to be very effective.

I have a particular business problem at work where I think that ABM, and Netlogo in particular, could be useful for generating consensus on a way forward between two groups that have entrenched and opposing views.

What I would like to do is to demonstrate models and alter parameters. Even better, if possible, I would like them to see me add to the model.

However, this is a corporate environment. I can not install software on my machine or indeed any machine that I can connect to their network.

Is there a way that I can, say, run this all off a stick, in the cloud or simply as a download/unzip without an install.

Could be worse. My work laptop does have JAVA installed. jre6.

Comment: Have you tried installing it to some folder other than Program Files (assuming you are on Windows, which is where this is usually a problem)? I have a directory called Installs, which I use for anything I want outside the UAC system (in this case Installs/NetLogo).

Answer (score 2):

"off a stick": yes, http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#runcd

"download/unzip without an install": Are you on Windows? I'll assume you are. We don't make a zip archive available for this purpose, but you can make one yourself by installing NetLogo on another machine and zipping up the resulting folder. Once you unzip on your work machine, the only thing you'll be missing is the association of the .nlogo and .nlogo3d file suffixes with the NetLogo application. (So yes, JenB's suggestion should work.)

Comment: Thanks, worked a treat. Installed on my home machine, copied the Program FIles (x86)/NetLogo 5.2.0 folder over to the work laptop. There, if I double click NetLogo 5.2.0.exe then I get the normal Netlogo goodness, Thanks again